# If the source of a morphism is a noetherian scheme, the morphism is quasi-compact.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, noetherian

I was wondering it while studying Hartshorne.

In II.4.8 proof of the corollary (This part is about valuative criterion of properness.), it is written that a morphism from noetherian scheme is automatically quasi-compact.

Precisely, for a noetherian scheme $X$, any morphism $f:X\rightarrow Y$ of schemes is quasi-compact.

But I cannot find why.

Could you give me any idea?

Comment: Every subset of a Noetherian space is quasi-compact.

Comment: Oh, even for not open subset?

Comment: Yes. This is actually a characterization of noetherian spaces i.e. noetherian iff every subspace is quasi-compact